# Can't access struct fields

Tags: c, codeblocks

Am i doing something wrong here:

I have 2 `structs`:

```
typedef struct Boundaries{
    int f[11];
    int t[11];
    int d[11];
} boundaries;

typedef struct STNODE {
    char name;
    int addr;
    const char* type;
    int  _size;
    boundaries b;
    int cell_size;
} stnode;
```

And i create an array of `stnode`:

```
stnode ST[24];
```

When i try to access the fields of `stnode` (i.e by a dot `'.'`) i get all the fields `name`,`addr`,`type`,`_size`,`b`,`cell_size`. Problem is i can't access `b`'s fields. This expression:

```
ST[i].b.
```

opens up the variables of `stnode`. Shouldn't it let me choose from `b`'s variables? (`f[]`,`t[]`,`d[]`)

Thanks

**edit:**

For those who didn't understand what i mean by "opens up the variables", here's a snapshot:

[image: variables_list]

Comment: What does this mean "opens up the variables"? Just type the variable name and compile the code. If it is not compiled, post the code and compilation error.

Comment: Assuming based on 'opens up the variables of' you are talking about auto complete aren't you? Plus code-blocks is also tagged.

Comment: If you write the expression yourself (`ST[i].b.f[1]`), does it compile?

Comment: OK guys i tried writing the expression ignoring the Auto Complete, and it compiled. I guess it's a stupid bug in codeblocks. If a run time error occurred regarding this i'll repost. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh now that I know what is this about.

Code::Blocks autocomplete is **just plain bad**, it will never do what you want it to. If it does what it's supposed to consider yourself lucky. I've been using code::blocks for like 5 years making complicated projects and most of the feature just failed for me because of whatever reasons.
On example is the error tracking, when you double click in the compile error it takes you to the file and the line the error occurred on, well this doesn't work if the path to the source is a relative path.
All I'm saying with this is that parsing is not the best and I've even seen the auto completion system simply crash under the hood refusing the show the help, I had to restart to make it work again.

Other than these some idoms affect how the auto completion handles things.
One of the most direct is the perprocessor, if a preprocessor directive handles the definition and you have to specify that explicitly the auto-completion will ignore that. One way to check if it's a problem with the auto-completion system simply copy the defintion you put in your question directly into the file you're using if it's not already there. If it doesn't work there, you can't do much about it. If it does work you should check how and where you include these defintions because it's possible that some preprocessor directive just knocks it out making it invisible for the auto-completion system.